# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined or <%%> ejs tag is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Movie App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/design.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Montserrat:400,700&display=swap">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="searchHeading">Search Result <span style="color: grey;"> =></span> <%= searchQuery.toUpperCase() %></h1>

    <% data["results"].forEach((movie)=> { %>

    <div class="card mb-5 w-75">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2<%=movie["poster_path"] %>
                    class="card-img img-fluid">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title"><%= movie["original_title"] %></h2>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="card-text"><%= movie["overview"] %></p>
                    <hr>
                    <br>
                    <p class="card-text"><b>Date Published:</b> <%= movie["release_date"] %> </p>
                    <p class="card-text"><b>Total Votes:</b> <%= movie["vote_count"] %> </p>
                    <p class="card-text"><b>Average Rating:</b> <%= movie["vote_average"] %> </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <% }); %>


</body>

</html>
```

Error: Cannot read property `forEach` of undefined

Comment: I have installed ejs correctly.But dont know why the script is not working.Checked whether the tags were the "problem" But couldn't verify them .

Comment: You may need post more information but source code. Like how you examine your code and what happened. It would be better if you have some error messages.

Comment: I am learning NodeJS and this project is a part of it.

Comment: This uses the API of moviedb website to list the searched movie . Simple .. To retrieve the information and display I am being taught to use EJS . I did what I have been taught. But I have no IDEA what happened there. If you have used EJS already and resolved this error please help me

Comment: The above code is starts with <body>           search results=> and I get error there by using ejs tag <% %> that the content inside it is not defines or undefined

Comment: `data["results"]` is `undefined`, find out why.

Comment: Found at the portion which caused error.It is not here.It is found in js file.Thank you for the response